# How to prevent JAWS screen reader from saying "read only" on div checkbox?

Tags: accessibility, readonly, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader, coveo

We are using [Coveo](https://www.coveo.com/en/solutions/coveo-for-sitecore) for their elaborate search capabilities on top of [Sitecore](https://www.sitecore.com/) CMS.

The filter facets to narrow down your search results generates a list of checkboxes with a `<div>` tag, and each of these along with text next to it is inside a `<li>`, which as a group are inside a `<ul>` (code sample below). Visually appears like so:

[image: Two checkboxes with label next to each]

Had to use jQuery to add my own attributes to make sure `div.coveo-facet-checkbox` was recognized/read as a checkbox by screen readers, which is working quite well with NVDA and ChromeVox.

However, JAWS has a slight issue that once focus moves into the `<ul>` list, the first `div.coveo-facet-checkbox` it will land on, JAWS will first announce "readonly".

Code **sample**:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" form="coveo-dummy-form" style="display:none;">
        <div class="coveo-facet-checkbox" tabindex="0" title="Education and Events" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false"></div>
        <span class="coveo-facet-value-caption" title="Education and Events" data-original-value="Education and Events" aria-hidden="true">Education and Events</span>
      </div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
      ...(structured same as above <li>)...
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried to add the attributes `readonly="false"` and `aria-readonly="false"` on ALL tag levels of code sample shared, and still JAWS chooses to announce "readonly"

Not sure what else to do/try. Tried to search online, but only found people complaining about similar sitiations, but with not fix/solution.

Any tips/tricks for me to try out would be appreciated.

*NOTE: Sorry if I cannot respond right away as I won't get much chance to be on computer until Monday (will edit this last line out when back).*

Comment: Have you read some examples on how to make custom accessible checkboxes? Can you modify the CSS or add additional CSS?

Comment: "`once focus moves into the <ul>`" - How do you move the focus? TAB to the <div> that has tabindex=0? DownArrow with JAWS to go to the next element in the accessibility tree? `L` shortcut key to move to the next list? `I` (eye) shortcut key to move to the next list item? Do all of these cause *"readonly"* to be announced? If all of these techniques are used to move to the **next** element, does it say *"readonly"* for those, or just the first one? Can you copy/paste the speech history output from JAWS (Ins+Space,H). Have you viewed the accessibility tree in chrome? Happens in FF, Chrome, IE?

Comment: Which version of the Coveo JavaScript Framework are you using? You can check it out by using `Coveo.version` in your browser's console. There have been a lot of Accessibility improvements starting with 2.4609.6, maybe those changes would help in your case: https://docs.coveo.com/en/1493/javascript-search-framework/august-2018-release-v2-4609-6

Comment: @Leon, yes can modify, however not entirely sure that adjusting the CSS will solve what the screen reader dictates.

Comment: @slugolicious, yes. In this case only when focus moves while using the Tab key, 'readonly' is announced once focus moves into the <ul> onto a checkbox (after focus moves from outside the <ul>, from previous tabable item). Tried to get history output, but a) nothing but shortcuts seem to be listed; and b) when I try to interact with the popup for this, it just closes.

Comment: @flguillemette, neat way of checking version! We are on 2.3826.13... thank you for tip. Devs are updating soon. A lot of pages/components need to be tested to make sure all is good with the update. In meantime, need to find a solution for this specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screen readers themselves are not 100% perfect and was able to trace this to the fact that the checkbox is inside the `<li>`.

Just by changing the role attribute of the `<li>` would change how the screen reader would announce when focus went to the checkbox.

So now to just decide which role to use. I came across `role="none"` which JAWS does support, but NVDA does not. However, since this is a JAWS specific issue, this seems like a good choice.

To apply changes like this after results are rendered by Coveo, the `deferredQuerySuccess` was used to improve the checkbox div:

```
// When Filter Facets are rendered.
Coveo.$$(document.body).on('deferredQuerySuccess', function (e, args) {

    // Set role for each li parent of Coveo's <div> checkboxes
    // to prevent JAWS screen reader from saying 'readonly'
    $('.coveo-facet-value.coveo-facet-selectable').attr('role', 'none');

});
```